# Can not install Ubuntu on Gigabyte UEFI Dual BIOS motherboard

Tags: 14.04, motherboard

I have burnt Ubuntu 14.04 64bit using Unetbooting on a USB flash drive and tried several times to install Ubuntu on my new computer which has no software on it and  Gigabyte GA-Z97P-D3 motherboard. It is a UEFI Dual BIOS and I guess the problem has something to do with UEFI.

It may also worth mentioning that the flash drive is formated to ext4.

The installer just hangs on Unetbootin blue page and does not proceed.
I have also tried Ubuntu 12.04 but got the same resutls.
Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: I assume the computer is brand new. If not, have you ever successfully installed any other OS via USB flash drive?

Comment: That's right Davide. The computer is brand new and it will be the first OS.

Comment: Well then, the easiest thing to try next would be to try a different distro... I'd suggest openSuse as their "usb flash drive image burning" procedure is different and can not be done with unetbootin. It's a shot in the dark, but it doesn't take very long... [Instructions here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick#Using_commandline_tools) I typically use way number 4 (commandline tools)

Comment: @Dadvide, I want to install Ubuntu. OpenSuse is my least favorite distro.

Comment: What I meant was, try to install it to see if a different distro also has the same issues, as trying this might help narrow down the problem a bit. This is Ask Ubuntu, of course you want to end up with Ubuntu installed

Answer (score 1):

Needed F6 (BIOS boot) to set ACPI=Off and nomodeset, add to grub if UEFI boot.

Gigabyte UEFI boot issues - The partition size of the created USB Installer device needs to be under that of 4GB. 
Others found UEFI/BIOS update solved issue of 4GB FAT limit.

turns out the IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to Gigabyte boards.

Gigabyte Z97-HD3 Intel Z97 Motherboard

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gigabyte_z97_hd3&num=1

Comment: So, in simple terms, what should I do to resolve the problem? I'm not a super geeky guy

Comment: You need to change some settings in UEFI, particularly the IOMMU setting. There may be other settings, those notes were from other users. I installed to a Asus z97-ar and had many UEFI settings that I had to change. If you have fast boot turn that off also, or at least for cold reboot, so you can get into UEFI to change settings. If not it may boot too fast to let you press keys to get into UEFI. With my Asus I had to change from Secure boot to Other and set to UEFI only. Most other settings were turning off timing tweaks as I wanted stable system above all.

Comment: I can not see any option in motherboard config page to change bloody UEFI settings.

Comment: My Asus UEFI was many pages, and some setting do not appear in sub-menus unless you can another setting perhaps even on another tab. Not sure with Gigabyte as I have not seen any posts of its UEFI screens.